# When should we (really) use RenderScript?

Tags: android, renderscript

I cannot seem to find a clear answer of when to use `RenderScript`?

Documentation says that we should use it when doing some computing or work with images. This is not so clear especially the part with images.

Can someone give me practical advices when to use it?

For example,

1. what computing are they talking about?
2. when should we use `RenderScript` dealing with `Bitmap` when there are other methods (or factories) which we can successfully use on such occasions?
3. Is `RenderScript` limited only to usage when coding games?

Comment: renderscript is a convenient way to access performant primitive functions from java without endlessly switching to native via JNI.

Comment: @njzk2 OK, it makes more sense now. But the question is still here: what calculations or bitmaps you would have to face to reach for `RenderScript`?

Comment: From what I get the images part is when making changes to images, like a photo editor, not to display a image in a ImageView

Comment: @nininho What about when have to do a lot of image resizing?

Answer (score 8):

Its really pretty simple.  If your application is doing a lot of cpu based data processing (i.e. in Dalvik or the NDK), and you would like a speedup, you should look at RS.

If you don't have a performance problem today I would keep doing what you are doing.

Comment: Are you saying, if I face "no more memory" issue while processing some algorithm, I should look at RS?